# Npm package to auto generate jsdocs and push to github

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I found this great npm package called [Wicked](https://github.com/thlorenz/wicked) that will auto-generate jsdocs for you and push them to github. However it's so old that in order to use it you have to be running Node version 0.10, so you have to change your node version, run it, and then change it back to the current version. This version is not going to be maintained after October of this year, so it's not really a viable solution.

Does anyone know of an npm package/combination of packages that is still being updated that will do the same thing?

Comment: This question could be considered "off topic" because it asks to "recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource". You should at least mention other libraries you've looked for to accomplish what you want before blindly asking for recommendations.

Comment: If you look at my post properly you'll see in my first sentence I say that I've been looking at Wicked and it does what I want, but it's not support on the latest node version.

Comment: Yes, but it's looking for recommendations as opposed to an actual solution and will be outdated at some point as a result.